# How can a result from one class can be used in another class

Tags: python, django

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

```
def get_queryset(self):  # new
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
    return object_list

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.object_list
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a get context data in your create view and pass to your template.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    context['object_list'] = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
    return context
```

Or in your form template add form tags with action attribute with search url

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I tried this method it not working but using same logic i got the object_list value. Is there any method to convert object_list value into "User" Instance. to save in place of     form.instance.author = object_list

Comment: if it is a different question ask it separately on stackoverflow.

Comment: user you can get from form.instance.author = self.request.user

Comment: Yes form.instance.author = self.request.user saves data under logged-in user id, but i want it to be saved under search result [ query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query)) ]  User id. When i tried to user object_list in place of self.request.user it gives error that it must be 'User' instance. I would like to know if this can be done or if there is any other method to do it.

Comment: try with Q(user__username__icontains=query

Comment: even that's not working --->  Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: User, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, post, profile, user_permissions, username

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and help. I got it done. Thank you.